# chrome extension works on refresh/on land but not on 'internal navigation'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So simply when I land a page on youtube which starts with w* (meaning that a specific video with its ID) I'm firing alert(url) and it works however it only works when I land that page from the URL and/or on refresh. **What I'm trying to achieve is to fire that alert when navigating to that page (watch?=...) FROM another youtube page meaning that I'm navigating internally.**

as an example:
[www.youtube.com](http://www.youtube.com) -> this is the landing page of youtube
I click on a video and I navigate to:
[www.youtube.com/watch?=aiFUQ9981Qk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?=aiFUQ9981Qk)

this DOES NOT trigger my alert HOWEVER when I refresh, it does trigger.
how do i trigger even when i navigate 'FROM' 'WITHIN' youtube ?
Any input would be appreciated. manifest and Content.js attached below...

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "youtest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/watch?*"],
            "js": ["Content.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Content.js

```
console.log(window.location.href);
alert(window.location.href);
```

Comment: I havent used chrome extensions before but I imagine you need a eventlistner perhaps listen to `popstate` and then run whatever you like

Comment: I think I've observed the problem. Thank you for your input. Not having a full page refresh seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function runScript() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('watch?') > -1) {
        alert('this is a video');
        let videoID = window.location.href.slice(
            window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')
        );
        alert(videoID);
    } else {
        alert('not a video');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('yt-navigate-start', runScript);
```